# VS2008. Make class defined in Project 1 visible in Project 2 inside the containing solution

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

How can I make a class defined in Project 1 visible so I can declare objects of that type inside Project 2, if both projects are part of the same solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on project 2, 
Press add reference 
Wait while VS2008 take for ever to load the add reference dialog 
Press the projects tab 
Select project 1

Answer (score 0):

If the classes in Project 1 are defined in a different namespace, reference the namespace and then the class in the second project. Something like:

```
Project1NameSpace.Class1 varName;
```

Alternately, put a using statement at the top of Project 2's source code, e.g.

```
using Project1NameSpace;
```

Then, all public or internal classes inside Project 1 should be available in Project 2. (This is all assuming that both projects are in the same solution, as you mentioned.)

Note: You may have to add a reference to the project in your solution.